# Regex Match string if it exists

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Example 1:

```
THE COMPANIES ACT 
(Cap 486)
IT IS notified
```

Example 2:

```
THE COMPANIES ACT
(Cap. 486)
Incorporations
IT IS notified
```

My current regex: `THE COMPANIES ACT\n\(((?:Cap.|Cap) .*?)\)(?:\nIncorporations|\nincorporations)\nIT IS notified`only matches Example 2.

I would like it to match both examples.

Comment: That's because the last parenthesized  part is required, not optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make `(?:\nIncorporations|\nincorporations)` optional by appending `?` (0 or 1 match) after it. Otherwise, the first example doesn't match as you have specified that you want to match `(?:\nIncorporations|\nincorporations)` in any case.

As `ncorporations` is common in both *ncorporations, you could consider `(?:\n[Ii]ncorporations)?` instead of `(?:\nIncorporations|\nincorporations)?` and `(?:Cap\.?)` instead of `(?:Cap.|Cap)`, to shorten it a bit and also to escape the dot (since `.` means any character).

Comment: Additionaly, he might consider using \n((I|i)ncorporations)? Since it is way shorter

Comment: @Raf Indeed! Another char shorter: `[Ii]` :)